# Optimizing my work - PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this flow of the work:

**Initialize.php** - queries the DB based on some algo. and prepares one ro (or none if there is no more)

**View.php** - shows the row content to the user and gives him a form to fill.

**Update.php** - When the user clicks on submit from the view, this php update the DB and calls initialize to have a new row prepared.

**The problem:** I have a 2-8 seconds of a waiting time between clicking on submit and getting the new row.
I have tried to optimize the code and the queries but it didnt help very much.

**My idea** is to change the flow so in initialize i will remember 2 rows. One will be presented in the tagging View and the second one is saved. When clicking the submit the user will receive this second row and while he is on the view, i want to prepare the next row. The question is - is it possible to implement using PHP and My**strong text**

Comment: First, find out what the bottleneck is. Just randomly "optimizing" things is not going to help you.

Comment: Your problem could be related to coding or db querying or IT ... you need to understand which is causing the slow performance and then solve it. I would recommend first try to manually run the exact queries on the DB and see the time it takes for it to operate, then create an empty php page located on the same server as the rest of your php site, that only runs manually that query and see the time it takes, after that you can pretty much understand what is causing the low performance, update you post and lets try to think this through...

Comment: How complicated is Update.php? As it seems from your description that is taking 2~8 seconds.

Comment: The slowness is caused not by the queries but because people who work on the site are using a remote connection.

Comment: @ Matan L - I already did it. All the queries and the code take approximately 1.5 seconds.

Comment: @Kickstart - Update is not that complicated, 2 queries of update. The most complicated is initial.php. There are 8 select and update queries there

Comment: @Alex if I've understood you correctly, running the code takes 1.5 seconds, while it takes 8-12 seconds to display the page on low-bandwidth devices.  This means that you are going to have to look at what you are sending to those clients that takes so long.  All of your external assets (JS, CSS, images) need to be reduced and delivered in a non-blocking manner. You need to avoid redirects, and so on.

Comment: To go with what @Matt says, if your delay is caused by a very slow connection anything you do with the queries will have minimal effect. If the issue is that you need the users to populate one screen and then another the solution would appear to be to merge both screens into one, or possibly use Ajax to avoid a full screen refresh (that way you are only sending a small amount of data on the Ajax requests).

Comment: @Kickstart - Most of the screen is having a new data, thats why AJAX is not an answer. The problem is the slow connection, thats why i am trying to understand if i can do something to solve it. Optimizing queries, as you said, wont help me

Comment: @Matt - what do you mean by "need to be reduced and delivered in a non-blocking manner"?

Comment: I think he means to generate the screen in a way that it isn't waiting for files (such as a large CSS file) before displaying the data usefully. Ajax might well help if a large amount of the current screen is formatting / html tags rather than just pure data. At least using Ajax you could load your 2nd row in the background once the page is loaded, merely then having to make it visible while you are using another Ajax call to save any updates to the first row you displayed. But just how slow are these connections?